# Calling static method from inside a task

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im having some problems with threading and delegates to other classes. Hope to get some better understanding what missing or wrong.
Right now I need to be able to call a static class from with in a Task that is running. There is not much to do about this as this in reality comes from a 3rd party library. I have tried some solutions to this but not working. Here is and simplified example of what I try to do.

```
namespace ThreadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task<string> designation = new Task<string>(delegate
            {
                return Global.SyncMethod();
            });

            var resolvedDesignation = designation.ContinueWith((i) => { return i.Result; });
            string result = resolvedDesignation.Result;


        }
    }

    public static class Global
    {
        public static string SyncMethod()
        {
            return "Return test";
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for this threading is to be able to of load the user from something that takes some time to process, with out locking up the UI. How ever, when trying to call the referred class it does not work. Any help for what is missing? It dose not throw any exceptions, only enters and skips out when its supposed to be executed.

Comment: Can you elaborate`it dose not work`?

Comment: _"does not work"_ is not very [helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). How exactly it is not working? Does it throw an exception? Does it block an UI thread?

Comment: Why do you use `ContinuteWith` and `.Result` when you can `await`?

Comment: There are no exceptions, it just dies. get ignored.

Comment: I have tried ´await´ dose not change its outcome.

Comment: [Don't use the `Task` constructors](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Comment: You probably want to `await Task.Run(Global.SyncMethod);`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow OP states that `Global.SyncMethod` is blocking the UI thread. In that case, `Task.Run` would invoke `Global.SyncMethod` on a thread-pool thread, keeping the UI thread free.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The difference is that `await` does not block the current (UI) thread; it schedules a continuation, but then releases the thread to do other UI stuff. Once the `Task` returned from `Task.Run` is competed, the remainder of the code can resume after the `await`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, Sorry, I don't know enough C# to continue. I have removed my previous questions from this thread.

Comment: I'm closing this down as this probably more has to do with 3rd party lib not being thread safe and there for must be encapsulated some how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the given example will just deadlock. You are essentially creating a task and blocking until it completes, but you are never starting it. So you will just block forever.

See the [documentation for task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start?view=net-6.0) or use [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0) to both create and start the task. But keep in mind, even if you are actually starting the task, it is rarely a good idea to block until it completes. It will not help your UI, since the UI thread will still be blocked, and it may still cause deadlocks in case the started task needs to do something on the UI thread.

Comment: You are probably right about this example result in a deadlock. I have tried multipla ways to write this code by threading. And I have read what you refer to at MS. This dose not how ever solve the issue when it comes to loading info of the static class from a method running inside the task that is running. That is the issue. 
Methods that is also processing a 3rd party lib is sought after to be offloaded to a thread thread, not to lock the UI. and on thread completion should return and proceed with the processed data.

Comment: @Jonas Lindahl if the called method is a pure method, as in your example, It is as safe as it could possibly be, so I have no idea what "loading info of the static class" means or why it should be a problem. I suspect your issue is that you have shared mutable state without proper synchronization, i.e. your code is not thread safe. But that is not something your example demonstrates.

Comment: So you are saying this could more be likely be an issue of the code that is 3rd party lib is not thread-safe. So where should I go from there? Only have it executed from the main thread?

Comment: @ Jonas Lindahl unless the documentation states otherwise, the standard practice is for static methods to be thread safe, and non static methods not to be thread safe. While the Microsoft supplied libraries follow this fairly well, third party libraries might not. If there is no documentation about the library it can be difficult to tell if it is safe or not, but you might be able to decompile it to check if the static method access any shared mutable state. But it's difficult to provide recommendations without more details.